# BUTTON要素とINPUT要素のTYPE=SUBMITの上ではBSキーの操作を無効にしたい

Tags: javascript, jquery

皆様　いつも大変御世話になっております。
標題の件を達成する上で、以下Javascript（JQuery）のコーディングを行いましたが、機能していないようで相変わらずボタンコントロールの上でバックスペースキーを操作すると、遷移元ページへ移動してしまいます。（当方IE利用）

====質問====
以下コーディングであやまっている部分、もしくは解決策のご教示をお願いできませんでしょうか．．．．。

```
//ボタンコントロール上ではバックスペースキー無効でページ遷移を防ぐ
        $("button, input[type=submit]").keypress(function(e){
            if((e.which == 8) || (e.keyCode == 8)){ return false; }
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ブラウザバックを禁止するのも一つの方法です。以下スクリプト例です

```
history.pushState(null, null, null);
window.addEventListener("popstate", function() {
    history.pushState(null, null, null);
});
```

pushState(state, title, url)のurlに　nullを指定し履歴へ追加しブラウザバックした時に　自分自身へ戻る様にします。

Comment: yyz様　いつもありがとうございます。確かにコピペしただけで、BSキーを押してもページが戻らなくなり大変参考になりました、解決策の一つとして採用を検討します

Comment: ブラウザの戻るボタンを押してもページが戻らなくなった点は、期待以上の効果です！